# Band Curvature looks like straight lines for (221) MoS2 Monolayer in Quantum ESPRESSO

Tags: quantum-espresso, band-structure

[image][image]In the band structure of (221) $\ce{MoS2}$ supercell, all the curvature are looking like straight lines. I cannot calculate band gap.

[image]

```
high-symmetry point:  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000   x coordinate   0.0000
high-symmetry point:  0.0000 0.3849 0.0000   x coordinate   0.3849
high-symmetry point:  0.0000-0.5774 0.0000   x coordinate   0.3849
high-symmetry point:  0.1667 0.2887 0.0000   x coordinate   1.2668
high-symmetry point:  0.1667 0.4811 0.0000   x coordinate   1.4593
high-symmetry point:  0.3333 0.5774 0.0000   x coordinate   1.6517
```

point group $C_{3v}$ (3m), there are  3 classes. The character table:

```
       E     2C3   3s_v 
A_1    1.00  1.00  1.00
A_2    1.00  1.00 -1.00
E      2.00 -1.00  0.00
```

Comment: Comment discussion has been moved to the [QE chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58530250#58530250)

Comment: Nithyadevi, have you made any progress on this? It would be nice to see an update (or a self-answer if you've figured it out!).

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.